# Find the exact coordinates of the centroid for the region bounded by the curves $y=\frac 1x$, $y=x$, $y=0$ and $x=2$

Tags: centroid

Im not sure how to set up these integrals. I tried using $y=x$ as the upper curve and subtract $y=\frac 1x$ in my integrals but I still am not getting the correct answer. If anyone knows how to do this and could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you draw a picture?

Comment: zipirovich is correct: Draw a graph of these 4 curves (it doesn't have to be some great accurate thing - just a quick drawing to see how they relate). Integrating the region bounded by these 4 curves nowhere involves an integral as you describe.